# Django's UnicodeEncodeError on session decoding

Tags: django, session, unicode, character-encoding

I reformat my mac and I suddenly can't login on my local django app admin. After submitting username and password it gives me :

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /login/
('ascii', u'\u324e\u3151\u544f\u7751\u324e\u7a49\u545a\u3041\u6d4d\u334d\u6d59\u6d52\u474d\u3455\u7a59\u6c4a\u445a\u7751\u7a4d\u3567\u544e\u6c42\u474d\u7849\u6a4d\u7955\u445a\u4171\u6e41\u7831\u5641\u4b55\u4764\u7a56\u4764\u764e\u3262\u7074\u5a0a\u4558\u5643\u5a51\u6233\u4a33\u5a72\u5257\u4178\u4d33\u0a75V\x01\x00\u0730\u018d\x01\x00\u70f0\u01fc\x01\x00\u0848\u04be\x01\x00\uec30\u018d\x01\x00\uf510\u018d\x01\x00\ua900@\x01\x00\u1618\u018e\x01\x00\ua5d0@\x01\x00\ua870@\x01\x00\u2d18\u0169\x01\x00\ub120\u0161\x01\x00\u4150A', 0, 49, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

That's the session data and when I printed it inside console its producing some chinese characters and I don't know why.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but: You're using database-backed sessions and you re-created your (MySQL, at a guess) with a different encoding than you had before?

Comment: Um nope, I've been using oracle since before I even reformat and when I restoed, I didn't even use the old dump, I just recreated the tables through syncdb. Any other guess?

Comment: I never really figured it out except that the venv I was using was causing it. So I just nuked it, created new one and it worked again.